# Windows build using unattend and ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, unattend-file

I need to build a windows 10 image, from USB, using an unattend file and install other software packages using ansible.  I have been an IT person for a long time, but don't' have any experience doing what I'm trying to do.  First of all, is what I'm trying to do possible, or is there a better way going about this?  Thank You.

Just looking for the best way to do a silent build of windows, from USB and then install other necessary software packages.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As it is written, this question will very likely attract opinion based answers and as such is considered [off-topic](/help/dont-ask). Moreover, it is not directly related to software development (in that case a specific loop or data handling problem in ansible for example) but to a system deployment issue which makes it even more off-topic. There's an other stackexchange site more suited for this type of question: https://superuser.com. You should still check there guidelines to adapt your question if needed: https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask